# Pattern recognition for products of variables

Tags: pattern-matching, products

Pattern recognition doesn't work as I would expect when trying to match products, for example

```
Cases[a[1] b[1] a[2] b[2], x___ a[k_] b[k_] -> k, All]
```

> {1}

```
Cases[a[1] b[1] a[2] b[2], a[k_] b[k_] -> k, All]
```

> {}

But none of these two return {1,2} as I would expect. How to cure this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works as expected. It matches the whole expression at once:

```
Cases[a[1] b[1] a[2] b[2], x___ a[k_] b[k_], All]
(* {a[1] a[2] b[1] b[2]} *)
```

If you want to get *all* possible matches, please look at [`ReplaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html), which:

> *attempts to transform the entire expression expr by applying a rule or list of rules in **all possible ways**, and returns a list of the results obtained.*

```
ReplaceList[a[1] b[1] a[2] b[2], x___ a[k_] b[k_] :> k]
(* {1, 2} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, it was really helpful! Also why does ReplaceList[a[1]^2 , x___ a[k_]^2 :> k] return {} instead of {1} ?

Comment: @AdrienMartina why are you using triple blank? Just use the regular blank, and make it optional: `ReplaceList[a[1]^2 , x_. a[k_]^2 :> k] `. But note that you can use plain `Cases` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

```
p = a[1] b[1] a[2] b[2];

SequenceCases[List @@ p, {a[k_], b[k_] ...} :> k]
```

{1, 2}